# Type of Generic seems worthless

Tags: vb.net, generics

Please see the code below:

```
Public Function ExecuteDynamicQuery(Of T As New)(ByVal sql As String, ByVal type As T) As List(Of T) Implements IGenie.ExecuteDynamicQuery
            Dim iConnectionBLL As iConnectionBLL = New clsConnectionBLL
            Dim paramValues() As DbParameter = New clsParameterValues().getParameterValues()
            Using conn As DbConnection = iConnectionBLL.getDatabaseTypeByDescription("Genie2"), _
                  rdr As DbDataReader = clsDatabaseHelper.ExecuteReader(conn, CommandType.Text, sql, paramValues)
                Dim list As List(Of T) = New List(Of T)
                While rdr.Read()
                    Dim hello As New T
                    Dim method As MethodInfo = GetType(clsType).GetMethod("PopulateDataReader")
                    method.Invoke(hello, New Object() {rdr})
                    list.Add(hello)
                End While

                Return list
            End Using
        End Function
```

Is there a way of executing the SQL statement above without passing in type as an arguement.  It seems a bit pointless - the only reason it is there is to let the function know the type of the generic.

Comment: Am I missing something?  I don't see anywhere in your example where you are using the `type` argument.

Comment: @Steven Doggart, the signatures is: Public Function ExecuteDynamicQuery(Of T As New)(ByVal sql As String, ByVal type As T) As List(Of T) Implements IGenie.ExecuteDynamicQuery (type is the second parameter).

Comment: Right, but why is it there?  I don't see the argument being used anywhere in the body of the method.

Comment: @StevenDoggart, if I removed the arguement I got this error from the calling code: Type parameter cannot be inferred (and hence the reason for the question).  Jon Skeet answered this question.

Comment: Please explain the downvote as I thought this was a reasonable question.

Comment: The down-vote didn't come from me :(

Comment: @Steven Doggart, I didn't mean to imply that you did (thats why I did not address you in the question). Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can change the method to not have the second parameter:

```
Public Function ExecuteDynamicQuery(Of T As New)(ByVal sql As String) As List(Of T) Implements IGenie.ExecuteDynamicQuery
```

However:

- You'd need to change `IGenie` as well
- The caller would then need to explicitly specify the type argument, instead of letting the compiler infer it on the basis of the argument (which would no longer be present)

Comment: Thanks I have tried this.  The error I get now from the calling code is: Type parameter cannot be inferred. I believe this is because I have not followed point two in your answer.  The calling code looks like this: Dim list3 As List(Of typeClearcoreAlternateNamesList) = IGenie.ExecuteDynamicQuery(tyClearcoreAlternateNamesQuery.SQLQuery).  Thanks.  +1.

Comment: @w0051977: Well yes - as I said, you need to specify the type argument explicitly in the method call now: `ExecuteDynamicQuery(Of typeClearcoreAlternateNamesList)(tyClearcoreAlternateNamesQuery.SQLQuery)`. You've got to tell the code the type you want *somewhere* - the compiler can infer it from an argument of type `T`, or you can specify it as a type argument, but you can't miss it out entirely.

Comment: Thanks.  Thats it.  I will mark as answered in three minutes.